# Handle Input on an Virtual Screenresolution with fixed aspectratio

Tags: java, android, libgdx

i use a Virtual Screenresolution at my Camera with a fixed aspec ratio. Init looks like this:

```
this.cam = new OrthographicCamera(Config.VIRTUAL_VIEW_WIDTH,
                Config.VIRTUAL_VIEW_HEIGHT);
        this.cam.setToOrtho(false, Config.VIRTUAL_VIEW_WIDTH,
                Config.VIRTUAL_VIEW_HEIGHT);
        // create our stage
        this.stage = new Stage(0, 0, true);
        this.stage.clear(); // always clear the stage too to not get double
                            // stuff in a stage

        stage.setCamera(cam);
//some more stuff
@Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        // this.cam.setToOrtho(false, width, height);

        // calculate new viewport
        float aspectRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
        float scale = 1f;
        Vector2 crop = new Vector2(0f, 0f);

        if (aspectRatio > Config.ASPECT_RATIO) {
            scale = (float) height / (float) Config.VIRTUAL_VIEW_HEIGHT;
            crop.x = (width - Config.VIRTUAL_VIEW_WIDTH * scale) / 2f;
        } else if (aspectRatio < Config.ASPECT_RATIO) {
            scale = (float) width / (float) Config.VIRTUAL_VIEW_WIDTH;
            crop.y = (height - Config.VIRTUAL_VIEW_HEIGHT * scale) / 2f;
        } else {
            scale = (float) width / (float) Config.VIRTUAL_VIEW_WIDTH;
        }

        float w = (float) Config.VIRTUAL_VIEW_WIDTH * scale;
        float h = (float) Config.VIRTUAL_VIEW_HEIGHT * scale;
        viewport = new Rectangle(crop.x, crop.y, w, h);
    }
```

The render itself is short:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    cam.update();
    // setting the viewport
    Gdx.gl.glViewport((int) viewport.x, (int) viewport.y,
            (int) viewport.width, (int) viewport.height);
    // the following code clears the screen with the given RGB color (black)
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // update and draw the stage actors
    stage.act(delta);
    stage.draw();
```

This works really good and i can work with my Virtual Resolution. But i got Problems with a Touchpad. I simply init it like this:

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

skin = new Skin();
        skin.add("knob", new Texture("touchpad/touchKnob.png"));
        skin.add("background", new Texture("touchpad/touchBackground.png"));

        style = new TouchpadStyle();
        // skin.add
        style.knob = skin.getDrawable("knob");
        style.background = skin.getDrawable("background");

        pad = new Touchpad(10, style);
        pad.setBounds(0, Config.VIRTUAL_VIEW_HEIGHT - 150, 150, 150);
        this.stage.addActor(pad);
```

If the screen doesn't fitting to the virtual screen it doesnt react on touches correct or even dont react because the pad would be in the upper left edge but is on the virtual cam in reallity.

Any suggestions how to solve that?

Here is a picture of it. The area you see never changes so you always see the whole map. I colored the area where the touchpad "is". Also got the same problem with Buttons in the Menü.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself with some help from an other forum. I changed the resize methode so the camera zooms out/in:

```
@Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        cam.viewportHeight = height;
        cam.viewportWidth = width;
        if (Config.VIRTUAL_VIEW_WIDTH / cam.viewportWidth < Config.VIRTUAL_VIEW_HEIGHT
                / cam.viewportHeight) {
            cam.zoom = Config.VIRTUAL_VIEW_HEIGHT / cam.viewportHeight;
        } else {
            cam.zoom = Config.VIRTUAL_VIEW_WIDTH / cam.viewportWidth;
        }
        cam.update(); // update it ;)
    }
```